# OpenCL program on amazon EC2 hanging at the end

Tags: amazon-ec2, opencl

I have a OpenCL C++ program that I'm running on a NVIDIA GPU-enabled EC2 instance. Quite often, at the end of the program, it hangs, and I end up having to stop the instance to get out of it.

Here is the end of my code, is there something that I should be doing differently?

```
/* Finalization */
ret = clFlush(command_queue);
printf("clFlush: %s\n", getErrorString(ret));
ret = clFinish(command_queue);
printf("clFinish: %s\n", getErrorString(ret));
ret = clReleaseMemObject(ymobj);
printf("clReleaseMemObject: %s\n", getErrorString(ret));
ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
printf("clReleaseProgram: %s\n", getErrorString(ret));
ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
printf("clReleaseKernel: %s\n", getErrorString(ret));
ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
printf("clReleaseCommandQueue: %s\n", getErrorString(ret));
ret = clReleaseContext(context);
printf("clReleaseContext: %s\n", getErrorString(ret));


free(source_str);

free(y);

exit(0);
```

Typically I can see that the output from the command following clFinish, but nothing after that.

Comment: The call to clFlush  is not required  as the clFinish function will  ensure that all command are issued to the device and have completed.